# HP laptop running 14.04 : Wireless not working

Tags: wireless, hp

I recently bought HP pavilion notebook 15 alongside windows10,I dual booted ubuntu 14.04,Wireless  connection is not working,what can i do?

Comment: if you open a terminal: hold down the control and alt and t buttons all at once .... then paste in this command inxi -Fxz and copy the result: select the text and right-click and you should see a copy option; and paste the result back here: then it can be seen what system you have

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** If you could [edit] your question and [provide more information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) that would help us help you!  **;-)**

Comment: We need more information. Please provide the exact model of your laptop, the wireless adapter installed in the laptop. Open terminal by Ctrl+Alt+t, then enter `sudo lshw -C network` then press enter key. Please put the output received in your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 0a
   serial: c8:d3:ff:cf:a0:3e
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4104000-b4104fff memory:b4100000-b4103fff
```

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b4000000-b4001fff